# How do I serve .aspx pages with Owin/Katana?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, self-hosting, katana

I have a console app that needs to self-host a web site. I have small middle-ware classes that authenticate and log. Every example I find online is usually just sending text or raw html. I need to serve an .aspx page. `Response.Redirect` doesn't seem to work. Below is the middleware that might serve the page. Or perhaps I'm approaching this wrong.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;    

using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

namespace MyMiddleware
{
    public class MyContentMiddleWare
    {
        public AppFunc MyContentAppFunc(AppFunc next)
        {
            AppFunc appFunc = async (IDictionary<string, object> environment) =>
            {
                IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>SERVE PAGE INSTEAD</h1>");
            };
            return appFunc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Owin is an specification, so it depends what is behind that, If ASP.NET Core is behind, no, you won't be able to run WebForms. And there is no plans for that either.

Comment: @kblok It's not Core. I'm `using Microsoft.Owin;` so I believe it's katana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serve aspx pages from inside Microsoft.Owin, they are tightly coupled to System.Web. What you can do is run Microsoft.Owin in the System.Web pipeline to augment the functionality with things like auth.

Comment: "you can take your aspx pages elsewhere" Maybe you should leave a reference, as I never heard of it.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about MVC's cshtml files. aspx hasn't been ported to Core.